# Any new arrangement for select_list in WATIR 6.0.2 waits until options got populated?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I have a question about select_list which got populated in run time according to the option of some other select list.

For an example If I choose motor car `make` in my select_list, then `model` select_list got populated. but the problem is, I have to wait for few seconds before I interact with `model` select_list otherwise it throws the error no options present(because it takes some time to populate). I find very interesting thing in WATIR 6.0.2 like

```
b.link(:id,'NewContactNewGenFromMenu_Link').wait_until(&:visible?).click
```

which first confirm the element present through implicit wait using `when_present`, then it waits until element visible, this is amazing change. But Is there anything to check whether select list options got populated? Is any new arrangement?

Comment: For the link example, I would expect you only need `b.link(:id,'NewContactNewGenFromMenu_Link').click`. The implicit `present` check means that Watir waits for the element to exist and be visible.

Comment: @JustinKo No, It checks whether element exist or not, it doesn't check whether element is visible or not. I faced the problem of 'Element is not visible'. What I am doing is, I am clicking poped up link 'New contact', this pop up when I click 'New', So the delay to appear few seconds is creating 'element is not visible error'.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is no change to the `Select#select` method in Watir 6.0.2 - ie it does not wait:

```
browser.select_list.select('changed_text')
#=> Watir::Exception::NoValueFoundException
```

You can get an implicit wait if you locate/select the option directly:

```
browser.select_list.option(text: 'changed_text').select
```

I think the wait functionality should be added to the `#select` and `#select_value` methods. I have opened [Issue 503](https://github.com/watir/watir/issues/503) to request the functionality.

Comment: I think you are talking from watir-classic, `b.select_list.select()` this select() function internally takes this option object and calls select method upon it. `So b.select_list(:id,id).select('hi')` and `b.select_list.option(:text,'hi').select` are same.

Comment: Thank you for raising request to add the functionality.

Comment: This was written about Watir, not Watir-Classic. If you take a look at the [`Select` class code](https://github.com/watir/watir/blob/master/lib/watir/elements/select.rb), the 2 approaches **are not** the same. The private `select_by_*` methods throw an exception as soon as no Selenium element is found. As a result, `b.select_list(:id,id).select('hi')` does not get the chance to wait for the option to be present. The fact that you get 2 different results for the 2 approaches also suggests they are not the same.

Comment: You have suggested there to include implicit wait. But if option doesn't present, then it doesn't immeditately throw the novaluefoundexpception, but this is an excepted behavior. It immediately needs to throw the error. So it should be like it gives some kind of function for user to choose whether to wait or not. Because user usually know which select_list it has to be waited for. So user has to choose whether to wait or not. So I should be like b.select_list.wait_until(&:OptionsPresent).select 'hi'

Comment: Are you saying that `#select` should just wait for the select list to have any option in it? Why wouldn't you want to wait for the specific option that you are trying to select?

Comment: First condition, not all select_list depends upon other select_list, So at that time, as soon as element is not present, it needs to throw the error. This is an expected behavior. But there are few select_list which depends upon other select_list where it needs to wait for options to get populated. So the control has to be given to the user. So I suggest the code should look like `b.select_list.wait_until(&:OptionsPresent?).select 'hi'` .

Comment: Given the new wait functionality, I would disagree that immediately throwing a no option present exception is expected. Selecting an option is really just a user clicking an option. If `Element#click` waits before clicking, then why shouldn't `Select#select`? Anyways, if those are your expectations, then you should add comments to argue against implementing [Issue 503](https://github.com/watir/watir/issues/503).

Comment: I am not sure whether you are understanding what I am saying. If select_list and it's option are fixed, then select_list.select() never fails. Never. Only when one select_list is populated by other select_list selection, select_list.select() fails because it attempt to select the element even before options are loaded. So it's only needed only when One select_list depends upon other select_list. Are you getting me now?

Comment: I understand, but I disagree that means a script needs to explicitly write `wait_until(&:OptionsPresent?)`. Try applying the same logic to clicking links. If the HTML of a page is static `link.click` never fails. Never. Only when another element/JavaScript changes the display of the link does `link.click` fail. Therefore the user should explicitly state when to wait for the link to appear. In other words, there should be no implicit wait. To me, that's what you are suggesting for select lists.

Comment: Okay, but what I most concerns is, Select_list selection never fails, it has never happened. So Select_list with fixed options has to immediately throws the error if there is no option present. Because it's only waste of time if it has to wait, I am talking from completely out of my experience. Do you know there are certain thing like 'b.text_field.exists?' also wait now, it's completely useless because it has to report to me immediately whether it exists or not, but it waits. I find it's all overhead to the existing good framework.

Comment: From my testing, `b.text_field.exists?` does not wait.

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right, I have mistaken somehow, Yesterday when I was checking it seems to be waiting. Yes you are right here, it's not waiting.

Comment: Hi I checked select_list with watir-webdriver and watir-classic, actually watir-webdriver waits for sometime but watir-classic immediately throws the error. Did you notice this?

Comment: No, I didn't notice. Are you sure that it is actually waiting as opposed to being slower? At least on a small page using Chrome, Watir-Webdriver appeared to fail instantly for me.

Comment: Yes,But I am checking in Internet Explorer. It's not slower, It waits for sometime.

Comment: Yes, you are right about chrome. It is not waiting while I try to automate in chrome.

Comment: Watir-Webdriver with IE also fails instantly for me (at least for a simple page).

Comment: Are you using WATIR 6.0.2 or are you requiring watir-webdriver directly? And Just now I have noticed that WATIR 6.0.2 is very slow when I use IE v11 but it's bit faster when I use IE v10.

Comment: Hi, this `hover` is not available for watir-classic? Because it's throwing `method_missing': undefined method `hover' for #<Watir::Link:0x2cfa600> (`

Comment: `require 'watir'
b = Watir::Browser.new :ie
b.goto 'bit.ly/watir-webdriver-demo'
s = b.select_list :id => 'entry_1000001'
s.select 'Ruby8'` Can you check this code Justin?

Comment: I am using Watir 6.0.2 when I say Watir-Webdriver (to make it clear I am not talking about Watir-Classic). No, there is no `hover` in Watir-Classic. Your code runs fine for me - it throws the exception right away for me (ie does not wait).

Comment: Don't know why, it waits for me while I use for IE. 

Then what do you do to perform the hover functionality in watir-classic? Any alternative?

Comment: You can try `fire_event(:onmouseover)`.